# Count does not count NumberString directly

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to count all `NumberStrings` in a list:

```
In[1]:= myList = {"123", "456", "789", "ab1", "cd2", "xyz"};
```

but, surprising (to me), I have to take a detour here:

```
In[2]:= Count[myList, NumberString]
Out[2]= 0
```

by using this explicit pattern specification:

```
In[3]:= Count[myList, _?(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString]&)]
Out[3]= 3
```

Any comments?

Comment: *String patterns* are not the same thing as *patterns*.

Comment: Linked topic should answer your question, let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Be sure you have learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.